# RACChannelTerminal on UISlider when is the nil override used

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

When does the nil value override come into play here:

```
RACChannelTerminal* sliderTerminal = [self.view.volumeSlider rac_newValueChannelWithNilValue:@0];
```

When the slider is receiving nil from the other terminal or when it's about to send a nil?

Answer (score 0):

The former - it replaces `nil` values that are sent on the following terminal which is the one the control (the slider) is subscribed to.

The internal implementations literally contains this snippet:

```
[channel.followingTerminal map:^(id value) {
  return value ?: nilValue;
}];
```

Comment: So the sliders sends the nil... why would that happen

Comment: Hm thats a different question than what you asked originally. Are you actually seeing this happening? Why do you even use `rac_newValueChannelWithNilValue` in the first place, what are you trying to achieven?

Comment: I have a slider that is linked to an external process ( a device) the problem is that sometimes the slider just jumps to the "nilValue" position for no reason ...

Comment: Well, seems like I mixed up the terminals when reading the code and it might be exactly the other way around after all. The nil value is applied to the `following` terminal which is the terminal that the control (the slider) subscribes to. That means the nil value  is coming from your external process which probably makes more sense

Comment: It would make sense if that process wouldn't have a ignore nil set on it :)